# Can i get mws auth token in multiple sites(1 amz account) in 1 time?

Tags: amazon-mws

My client is selling product in 3 site (US,CA,Mexico) with a same amazon account. 
Now he is want using our tool to manage their business in 3 site, first he need to give us the auth token.

So the question is coming:
**Does he need authorize to us 3 times in (amazonservices.com, amazonservices.ca, amazonservices.com.mx) or he only need authorize us in amazonservices.com ?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At least in the EU only one authorisation is needed. We can use the same credentials on for example .com, .co.uk or .fr.
Multiple credentials are needed if you are using multiple accounts. With one account, one authorisation is enough.